# How to access Laravel Class in the View?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I were in the **controller**, this line would do it.

`use App\UBBUserSetting, App\UBBSetting;`

---

## But I am in the view

I'm trying to include my classes in my view (**.blade.php**)

I can't

```
    use App\UBBUserSetting, App\UBBSetting;


    $ubb_user_settings = UBBUserSetting::where('cpe_mac','=',$cpe_mac)->get();
    $ubb_settings = UBBSetting::where('cpe_mac','=',$cpe_mac)->first();
    if($ubb_settings != null){
        $jump_bandwidth = $ubb_settings->jump_bandwidth;
        $paid = $ubb_settings->price_per_jump;
    }

    $option2 = 0;

    if($ubb_user_settings != null){
        $option1_selected = [];
        $option2_selected = [];

        $lines = count($ubb_user_settings);

        foreach ($ubb_user_settings as $i => $ubb_user_setting) {
            if($ubb_user_setting->option == 1){
                $option1_selected[$i]['d'] = $ubb_user_setting->created_at->format('d');
                $option1_selected[$i]['threshold'] = (int)$ubb_user_setting->volume_current_limit;

            }else{

                $option2++;
                $option2_selected[$i]['d'] = $ubb_user_setting->created_at->format('d');
                $option2_selected[$i]['threshold'] = (int)$ubb_user_setting->volume_current_limit;
                $option2_selected[$i]['next_threshold'] = $threshold + ($jump_bandwidth * $option2);

            }
        }

    }
```

---

## Error

[image]

---

How would one go about and did this ?

Any hints ?

Comment: Isn't this a conflict of interest with how Laravel is intended to work? Shouldn't you pass the data to the view, rather than run the code in the view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to use any PHP code in Blade views, use `<?php ?>` tags and you can use full namespace:

```
<?php
    ....
    $ubb_user_settings = \App\UBBUserSetting::where('cpe_mac','=',$cpe_mac)->get();
    ....
?>
```

But it's a terrible practice to run queries from views. You should really learn MVC pattern.

Comment: Yes, they're in `<?php`

Answer (score 3):

This should be your code:

```
$ubb_user_settings = \App\UBBUserSetting::where('cpe_mac','=',$cpe_mac)->get();
$ubb_settings = \App\UBBSetting::where('cpe_mac','=',$cpe_mac)->first();
if($ubb_settings != null){
    $jump_bandwidth = $ubb_settings->jump_bandwidth;
    $paid = $ubb_settings->price_per_jump;
}

$option2 = 0;

if($ubb_user_settings != null){
    $option1_selected = [];
    $option2_selected = [];

    $lines = count($ubb_user_settings);

    foreach ($ubb_user_settings as $i => $ubb_user_setting) {
        if($ubb_user_setting->option == 1){
            $option1_selected[$i]['d'] = $ubb_user_setting->created_at->format('d');
            $option1_selected[$i]['threshold'] = (int)$ubb_user_setting->volume_current_limit;

        }else{

            $option2++;
            $option2_selected[$i]['d'] = $ubb_user_setting->created_at->format('d');
            $option2_selected[$i]['threshold'] = (int)$ubb_user_setting->volume_current_limit;
            $option2_selected[$i]['next_threshold'] = $threshold + ($jump_bandwidth * $option2);

        }
    }

}
```

You can set the namespace before the class, so it will be `App\UBBUserSetting` before the `::where()`. Because you're in the blade view and not in a class you should use the namespace before the class.

Hope this works!

Comment: @ihue thank you! If this solved your problem you can accept this answer so other developers can see this works!

Answer (score 3):

do it separate:

```
use App\UBBUserSetting;
use App\UBBSetting;
```

Answer (score 0):

Write It This way

```
@php
use App\UBBUserSetting;
use App\UBBSetting;
@endphp
```